# How to find out if a numeric type is signed or unsigned in C#

Tags: c#, reflection

I want to know details about the type of a field by reflection.

I know I can find out that it is a value type with `Type.IsValueType`. But from there how do I know it is a number? A fixed point number? Signed or unsigned??

Is there anything like `Type.IsSigned`?

Comment: What do you mean by "unknown"?  Is it `dynamic`?  Is it an `object`?  Elaborate please.

Comment: You'll have to compare the type with all the CLR's signed types to see if it's one of them.

Comment: You probably do something like 1if typeof(myVar) == typeof(int))`, or `if (myvar is ulong)`...

Comment: @rory.ap: the algorithm does not know which class it will be working on, therefore I must use reflection - I rephrased out that "unknown"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There aren't that many numeric types that are unsigned, so why not compose a list of that:

```
if (new Type[] { typeof(ushort), typeof(uint), typeof(ulong), typeof(byte) }.Contains(type))
{
    // unsigned.
}
```

Or if you just want to compare the value (here `o`):

```
if (o is ushort || o is uint || o is ulong || o is byte)
{
    // unsigned.
}
```

Comment: Well, thanks. That explicit list of types was my first thought, just hoped there would be a more elegant solution...